# Dataflow on AppEngine giving access denied

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-dataflow

I am trying to run my dataflow program on appEngine but when i run it locally using mvn appengine:deveserver , it gives below  access denied exception

```
[INFO] WARNING: Error for /AppEngineDataFlow
[INFO] org.xerial.snappy.SnappyError: [FAILED_TO_LOAD_NATIVE_LIBRARY] access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "C:\Users\KAPIL~1.KUM\AppData\Local\Temp" "read")
[INFO]  at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyLoader.load(SnappyLoader.java:159)
[INFO]  at org.xerial.snappy.Snappy.<clinit>(Snappy.java:47)
```

I am trying to send pipeline arguments as below:

```
 String[] args = new String[]{"--project=adtech-core","--stagingLocation=gs://adtech-nyt-net/Ad-Delivery/test", "--runner=BlockingDataflowPipelineRunner", "--numWorkers=10", "--filesToStage=gs://adtech-nyt-net/Ad-Delivery/stage","--maxNumWorkers=15", "--inputDate=20160617_2"}

ProcessDFPLogFilesOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args).withValidation().as(ProcessDFPLogFilesOptions.class);     
Pipeline pipeline = Pipeline.create(options);
PCollection<String> dfp_network_data_log = pipeline.apply(TextIO.Read.named("ReadLines").from(_bucket_location).withCompressionType(TextIO.CompressionType.AUTO));
```

Comment: how did you fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

The standard AppEngine environment lacks the dependencies necessary to run the Dataflow Java SDK.  As recommended in [Scheduling Dataflow pipelines using App Engine Cron Service or Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/2016/04/scheduling-dataflow-pipelines-using-app-engine-cron-service-or-cloud-functions), you will want to use the `flexible` environment for running on AppEngine.